# Why does my AI move only 3 times before sending out an error?

Tags: javascript, html

I am coding an AI but I'm trying to get it to randomly move. Here is the code. If you check it on JSFiddle, then you should see that it only executes thrice.

I don't understand why it is not working. I have checked it through many times and found nothing. any help would be appreciated. :)

```js
class neuron {
  constructor(id, stage, connected) {
    this.id = id;
    this.stage = stage;
    this.connected = connected;
  }
}
var AI = document.getElementById("AI");
var size = 86;
var input = [];
var hiddenlayers = [];
var output = [];
var brain = [];
var xpos = 500;
var ypos = 500;
var interval = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  if (i < (size / 3)) {
    input.push(new neuron(i, "input", Math.floor((Math.random() * size) + 1)));
    while (input[input.length - 1].connected < size / 3 * 2) {
      input[input.length - 1].connected = Math.floor((Math.random() * size) + 1)
    }
  } else if (i < (size / 3 * 2)) {
    hiddenlayers.push(new neuron(i, "hidden", Math.floor((Math.random() * size) + 1)));
  } else {
    output.push(new neuron(i, "output", Math.floor((Math.random() * size) + 1)));
    while (output[output.length - 1].connected > size - (size / 3)) {
      output[output.length - 1].connected = Math.floor((Math.random() * size + 1))
    }
  }
}
brain.push(input);
brain.push(hiddenlayers);
brain.push(output);

function moveWithBrain() {
  if (interval == 0) {
    interval = 0;
  }
  if (interval % 2 === 0 || interval === 0) {
    if (brain[interval][0].connected % 2 === 0) {
      xpos -= 50;
      AI.style.left = xpos + "px";
    } else if (interval % 2 != 0) {
      xpos += 50;
      AI.style.left = xpos + "px";
    }
  } else if (interval % 2 != 0) {
    if (brain[interval][0].connected % 2 === 0) {
      ypos -= 50;
      AI.style.top = ypos + "px";
    } else if (interval % 2 != 0) {
      ypos += 50;
      AI.style.top = ypos + "px";
    }
  }
  interval++;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="moveWithBrain()">Move</button>
<div style="position: relative; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: blue; top: 500px; left: 500px;" onclick="moveWithBrain()" id="AI"></div>
```

Comment: welcome! please be super specific as to what is going on and what you attempted to solving the problem.

Comment: How are you currently "checking" it?

Comment: Add `console.log(interval,brain[interval])` before this `if (brain[interval][0].connected % 2 === 0) {` - your brain has 3 entries but you try to access the 4th

Comment: @DaveNewton I have been scouring through every line of code, trying to find the error, I now see thanks to mplungjan's comment what went wrong.

Comment: @PositivelyChargedElectron "Scouring the code" is good, but not always *efficient*. Logging, stepping through code, bisecting and removing chunks of code, "playing computer" with pencil and paper, etc. are almost always faster (and more accurate) than doing things in your head. Especially when it's targeted at something where you know the trigger condition.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks!